# Vivo ZX1 1917 Android 11 is not working while debugging on Android Studio as well as on Visual Studio

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio, android-studio

Vivo Android 11 phone have some issues, I have attached the Log Message below:

```
  Launching lib\main.dart on vivo 1917 in debug mode...
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
  Parameter format not correct -
  √  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
  Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
  D/FlutterGeolocator(29288): Attaching Geolocator to activity
  I/flutter (29288): **The Dart VM service is listening on 
  **************************************
  D/FlutterGeolocator(29288): Creating service.
  D/FlutterGeolocator(29288): Binding to location service.
  D/FlutterLocationService(29288): Creating service.
  D/FlutterLocationService(29288): Binding to location service.
  D/FlutterGeolocator(29288): Geolocator foreground service connected
  D/FlutterGeolocator(29288): Initializing Geolocator services
```

Many developers have issues with Vivo phones after the update from Android 10 to 11
the link referred to the same problem
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82520